# Focus first focusable element below a Focus widget

Tags: flutter

I am trying to focus the first focusable element below a `Focus` widget. Consider the following artifical example. It contains a `BarWidget` with some `TextField`.

The `FooWidget` wraps it into a `Focus` widget with the given `focusNode`. After one second, I'd like to focus the first element of `BarWidget`. Please not that I don't want to pass a `FocusNode` down into `BarWidget`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Foo());
}

class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => FooState();
}

class FooState extends State<Foo> {
  final focusNode = FocusNode();

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      focusNode.requestFocus,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Focus(
            focusNode: focusNode,
            child: BarWidget(),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class BarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(
        children: [
          Text("Foo"),
          TextField(),
          Text("Bar"),
        ],
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is in theory possible by using `FocusTraversalPolicy.sortDescendants`. However, that method is declared as `@protected`. See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70534

Full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Foo());
}

class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => FooState();
}

class FooState extends State<Foo> {
  final focusNode = FocusNode(canRequestFocus: false);

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    void f() {
      final policy = FocusTraversalGroup.of(focusNode.context);
      // ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member
      final node = policy.sortDescendants(focusNode.traversalDescendants, null).first;
      node.requestFocus();
    }
    Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      f,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Focus(
            focusNode: focusNode,
            child: BarWidget(),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class BarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(
        children: [
          Text("Foo"),
          TextField(),
          Text("Bar"),
        ],
      );
}
```